# How do you differentiate $\ln(\exp(z))$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, exponential-sum, derived-functors, q-analogs

I thought it can be simplified to $\ln(e^z)$

I then thought $e^x$ differentiated is $e^x$ so I thought the $\exp$ part would stay the same

I then thought $\ln x = \frac 1 x$

So I put it all together and decided $\ln(\exp(z))$ derived is $\frac 1 {e^z}$ but I feel this is so wrong.

Comment: $exp(z)$ and $e^z$ are actually very different functions when it comes to complex numbers

Comment: @Malcolm how so?

Comment: $e^z=exp(z)$ only in special cases. $exp(z)$ is called the principle value of the multi-valued exponential function $e^z$ 
In general, $e^z=exp(z).exp(2k\pi i z)$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and only is equal when $k=0$

Comment: Just a comment: You have written $\ln{x} = \frac{1}{x}$ in your problem. This is clearly not true. Be careful with your equalities!

Comment: @Malcolm: I think you might be getting the exponential mixed up with the logarithm. The exponential is holomorphic and single-valued.

Comment: @Joppy
Yes $\exp(z)$ is indeed entire. But $e^z = \exp(zLog(e))$. Note that in the principal branch $log(e)=1$ and thus $e^z=\exp(z)$ but since $Log(e)=ln|e|+iArg(e) =1+i(0+i2\pi k)$ then $e^z=\exp(z+iz2\pi k)$

This means if you take something like $e^\pi =\exp(\pi)(cos(2\pi ^2 k)+i sin(2\pi ^2 k))$ which has different values for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @KennyLau The above comments.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \ln(\exp(z))
&=& \displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\exp(z)} \ln(\exp(z)) \cdot \frac{\mathrm d\exp(z)}{\mathrm dz} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{\exp(z)} \cdot \exp(z) \\
&=& \displaystyle 1 \\
\end{array}$$

On a trivial remark, $\ln(\exp(z)) \equiv z$, so $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \ln(\exp(z)) = \displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} z = 1$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer thanks, edited.